# SL4 data binding syntax issue (debugging declarative databinding)

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, silverlight-4.0

I'm using the DevExpress GridControl with a context menu. Their context menu implementation uses their bars control which creates a lose reference from a row in the grid to a group of reusable bars. What this means is the context menu items don't have the same context as the grid (sparing details).

I can bind the command (ala ICommand) property of the bar to a command I've creaed on my view model. The challenge is I can't get my syntax to work just right. The VM is set to the DataContext of the view, but something like this isn't workign (where the view's x:name is "VideoModulePage):

```
Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ViewVideoCommand, ElementName=VideoModulePage}"
```

When I create this databinding expression in Blend/VS2010, it makes me thing this is valid, but the command isn't being fired. The CanExecute always returns true. Is this syntax valid? Any tips on a better approach to this? I think what I really need is the new SL5 databinding debugging now! :(

Here's a post I put in the DevExpress forum, but I don't think my issue is with their control, rather with my databinding syntax: http://community.devexpress.com/forums/t/96068.aspx

Comment: Just to make sure, are you binding the CommandParameter as well? You can also view binding errors in visual studio's output window, sometimes it helps tracking what's wrong.